# access application through a specific node/app server in websphere

Tags: routing, port, websphere

i have an application hosted in websphere 6.1.
there are 4 application servers in a single node. each app server has its own http, listener port numbers.

what i am trying to do is access the application through a specific node, say:

**http://[domain]:[appPort#]/ContextRoot**

such that, if the listener port number [appPort#] is app server 1's, then i access the application in app server 1..

my other question is, what will be this [appPort#]? is it the http (WC_defaulthost_secure) port number or SAS_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS, CSIV2_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS , CSIV2_SSL_MUTUALAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS?

does it require any additional firewall rules to be enabled on these ports or any other settings?

please assist.

Answer (score 2):

If you hit the server's hostname/IP on its `WC_defaulthost` port, you will indeed be directly hitting the Web Container of that specific server.

Only that port needs to be opened in your firewall(s).

`WC_defaulthost_secure` is if you're using https and have the Web Container configured to listen on that.